# SQLiteConnection not accepting sting as argument

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite.net

I am trying to connect to a SQLite .db file by using some examples that I found on the internet:

```
var m_connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Tabs.db;version=3;");
```

However, Visual Studio 2015 won't accept that because it says it doensn't accept just one argument.

> SQLiteConnection.SQLiteConnection(SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLitePlatform,
>   string, bool, SQLite.Net.IBlobSerializer,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary,
>   SQLite.Net.IContractResolver)

is what shows up in the object browser.
All of the examples seem straightforward, what am I encountering?
I downloaded SQLite.Net-PCL 3.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like you are confusing system.data.sqlite https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki (from the sqlite team) with sqlite.net https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL

Sqlite.net does not have a single string constructor.

If you are working on windows only I suggest you use system.data.sqlite (or consult the sqlite.net documentation)